# Google apps script update specific cell based on if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently, my script is updating all cells within the selected range with "YES" but I only want it to update cells that meet the if conditions. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//Active spreadsheet var that can be used anywhere in the programme
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get and check if there is an email address
function checkSendEmailAdd () {

  //Getting the array of values 
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var emailCol = activeSheet.getRange(2, 9, activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
//Looping over the array of values
      emailCol.forEach(function(val){
      var email = val[0].toLowerCase();
      var sentEmail = val[1];
      //If the send date column is empty and the email column has a @ within the string an email will be sent           
          if (email.indexOf("@") !== -1 && sentEmail == ""){

              //Email contents
              var subject = "Survey";
              var body = "Hi" + "<br><br>" +
                         "Testing 123";

               GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", { htmlBody: body } );

                //Update and set a new value in the sent email column
                var newSetValue = "YES";
                var updateSentEmail = activeSheet.getRange(2, 10, activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValue(newSetValue);

          } else {
          }
      });
```

The problem I'm facing is that the sent column is updating every cell but I only want it to update the cells that have an email in the email column.

[Image of what is being executed currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB1fU.png)

Comment: Welcome. The script isn't complete and the question doesn't include enough details. What value(s) have emailCol.? Ref. [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Rubén Thanks for the welcome and the advice. I've now updated the post to include the code and outlined the issue a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

I tried to determine the columns from your question.  I believe email was column one and sentMail was column two but if I'm wrong you can change them to whatever you need.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var sentA=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var html='';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var email=vA[i][0].toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    var sentEmail=vA[i][1];
    if(email && email.indexOf("@")>-1 && !sentEmail){
      var subject = "Survey";
      var body = "Hi<br><br>Testing 123";

      //GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", { htmlBody: body } );
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s -<br />Email: %s<br />Subject: %s<br />Body: %s<br /><hr/>', Number(i+1),email,subject,body);
      sentA[i][0]="Yes";
    } 
  }
  sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(sentA);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Emails Sent');
}
```

Spreadsheet before sending:

[image]

Spreadsheet after sending:

[image]

I removed the Gmail line and used a dialog to display the emails:

[image]

Comment: Hey Copper, Thanks for this, your assumptions are right. Only issues I'm facing is when I leave a few spaces in the email column and input an email further down the sheet, the whole range in the sent email column instead of the ones that match the if condition.

Comment: Please see the image attached to the post for a visual of what I'm trying to communicate.

Comment: try this: `var email=vA[i][0].toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    var sentEmail=vA[i][1];
    if(email && email.indexOf("@")>-1 && !sentEmail){`